# Bitcoin formatting via Blockchain API

Tags: c#, formatting, string-formatting, bitcoin

I am using the Blockchain api at:
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp/blob/master/docs/blockexplorer.md

and I am using on of the functions:
var address = blockExplorer.GetAddress(myAddress);

which for a balance of: 0.03644624 BTC will return the number: 3644624

Now what I am trying to do is get this returned number back into the format: 0.00000000

I am wondering what would be the best and most efficient way of doing this?
I am assuming if I got the number: 113644624 returned it would then be: 1.13644624 when formatted correctly.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there some reason why you simply can't divide your value by 10^8 ?

Comment: like:   long totalAfter = totalBefore / (10 ^ 8);  ?

Comment: Pete, that won't work as ^ operator in C# is a bitwise operator, I used ^ as a non language specific explanation. Instead see answer below for C# implementation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
var address = 3644624;
var t = address * Math.Pow(10,-8);
```